# xPath in operator syntax

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to check if there is an xml element with the value of S_NATIONKEY in a certain list (for this example, just 22,23).
I am not familiar with this syntax, and I am getting the following exception:

> .xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException:
>   javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Expected ), but found: ,

A sample xml which I am using to test this functionality would be:

```
<table ID="supplier">
    <T>
        <S_SUPPKEY>1</S_SUPPKEY>
        <S_NAME>Supplier#000000001</S_NAME>
        <S_ADDRESS> N kD4on9OM Ipw3,gf0JBoQDd7tgrzrddZ</S_ADDRESS>
        <S_NATIONKEY>17</S_NATIONKEY>
        <S_PHONE>27-918-335-1736</S_PHONE>
        <S_ACCTBAL>5755.94</S_ACCTBAL>
        <S_COMMENT>requests haggle carefully. accounts sublate finally. carefully ironic pa</S_COMMENT>
    </T>
    <T>
        <S_SUPPKEY>2</S_SUPPKEY>
        <S_NAME>Supplier#000000002</S_NAME>
        <S_ADDRESS>89eJ5ksX3ImxJQBvxObC,</S_ADDRESS>
        <S_NATIONKEY>5</S_NATIONKEY>
        <S_PHONE>15-679-861-2259</S_PHONE>
        <S_ACCTBAL>4032.68</S_ACCTBAL>
        <S_COMMENT>furiously stealthy frays thrash alongside of the slyly express deposits. blithely regular req</S_COMMENT>
    </T>
    <T>
        <S_SUPPKEY>3</S_SUPPKEY>
        <S_NAME>Supplier#000000003</S_NAME>
        <S_ADDRESS>q1,G3Pj6OjIuUYfUoH18BFTKP5aU9bEV3</S_ADDRESS>
        <S_NATIONKEY>1</S_NATIONKEY>
        <S_PHONE>11-383-516-1199</S_PHONE>
        <S_ACCTBAL>4192.40</S_ACCTBAL>
        <S_COMMENT>furiously regular instructions impress slyly! carefu</S_COMMENT>
    </T>
</table>
```

The expression I'm trying to use is:

```
/table/T[S_NATIONKEY=(22,23)]
```

xPath version is 2.x

Thank you!

Comment: The error message seems to indicate that you're actually using XPATH 1.0.

Comment: The error message *definitely* indicates XPath 1.0 only, but there's a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60438929/290085).

Comment: If your question has been answered, you should [**accept**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/234215) the answer that has most helped you.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You may believe that your processor implements XPath 2.0, but the error message definitely indicates that it only implements XPath 1.0.

### Solution

Rewrite the **XPath 2.0** expression,

```
/table/T[S_NATIONKEY=(22,23)]
```

to this in **XPath 1.0**:

```
/table/T[S_NATIONKEY=22 or S_NATIONKEY=23]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue with the xpath

```
/table/T[S_NATIONKEY=(1,5)]
```

[image]